# Chrome remembers old javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am developing a website with ASP.NET where as my test & development browser I am using Google Chrome (I surely do tests with other browsers, but this is not the problem I am having right now).

The problem which occurs and I cannot get rid of it is, that for unknown reason (to me) my Google Chrome still remembers the JavaScript file I have written several days ago and refuses to load the new (updated one) with much more code.

How can I force Google Chrome to refresh the JavaScript files I have developed? (I have no problem with CSS files, only JavaScript).

Comment: You can open up Devtools and check the option to Disable Cache (while DevTools is open) in Settings

Comment: Or simply Ctrl + F5

Answer (score 2):

Append revisions where you define scripts and update it each time..

```
<script src="test.js?rev=1"></script>
```

append rev="random number"

Comment: worked like a charm! Apart from this, is there a way how to do it via button click let's say? (e.g. I go to Chrome settings and maybe delete something there)

Comment: Do you mean deleting chrome caches?

Answer (score 0):

When the javascript file is called can you add a tag ?v=2
For example:

```
<script src="demo.js"></script>
will become:
<script src="demo.js?v=2"></script>
so it will not use the cached copy..
```